# generating tables from jpa with limited character length

Tags: java, jpa, varchar, longtext

I want to create a text field in a database with varchar(700) (I want 700 characters max).
I tried to define it like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_foo)
public class Foo {

@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
@Id
private String idNational;

@Column(length=700)
private String comment;
```

...

The table generate has the following properties:

```
idNational varchar(255) NOT NULL

comment longtext NULL
```

I would really like the comment to be varchar(700).  Is there a reason it makes it a longtext? Is there a way I can make it varchar?  Maybe this is an easy question, but I haven't found the solution!  Do I have to create the tables with DDL instead?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's problem with JPA provider configuration.
Better solution is cretion of tables with DDL.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say which database/version you're using but it sounds like a version of MySQL with a maximum length of 255 for varchar. The latest version supports larger varchars.

Since you're specifying a value > 255, it's using longtext instead.

MySQL 5.0.3 and later support varchars with length to 65,535 - earlier versions only 255.

Comment: You are right, I will remember to put my versions in next time!  I am using 5.1.43 - so I created the tables by DDL, and they are 700 characters now ...